# Azure AD B2B SSO with a multi-tenant application, I'm getting a response like "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have used the following permissions:

[image]

```
public void Test()
{
    try
    {


        string tenantId = User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?scope=openid%20profile%20User.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All%20Sites.ReadWrite.All%20Contacts.ReadWrite%20People.Read%20Notes.ReadWrite.All%20Tasks.ReadWrite%20Mail.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite.All%20Calendars.ReadWrite";
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        string clientId = "XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX";
        string secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result.AccessToken;
        var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(requestMessage =>
           {
               requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
               return Task.FromResult(0);
           }));

        var _users = graphserviceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync().Result;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}


public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {

            string tenantId = User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            string ClientID = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx";

            ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/" + tenantId), async () => await GetAppTokenAsync(tenantId).ConfigureAwait(true));

            try
            {
                var naaaewuser = adClient.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
return View();
}
```

> "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied"
>
> "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Can anyone help me how can I get users list of an organization who has signed in without “Admin Consent”? Also, please let me know if there is any alternative for this.

Thank you

Comment: Since you use the v2 endpoint as the authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/common/oauth2/v2.0`, did you register the app at apps.dev.microsoft.com?

Comment: Yes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627472/azure-active-directory-b2b-single-sign-on-with-multi-tenant-application-in-asp-n
This is the same question that i have already asked but is too large please check this one also

Comment: Your authority should be just `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/common/oauth2/v2.0` btw

Comment: And isn't `GraphServiceClient` for Azure AD Graph? You should probably use the token with the MS Graph client. *Though it might work on both..*

Comment: You are using only client credentials to get access. You need admin consent to get app permissions (which you will use in that case).

Comment: @juunas- Yes right, but I want list of users without admin consent

Comment: Then you need to use another authentication flow like Authorization Code.

Comment: @juunas - May I know how to use Authorization Code? Any document?

Comment: Can we discuss into the chat room? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181263/azure-ad

Comment: Got solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734558/4689622 
Thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution and get users basic profile of my organization. Solution: Get Access token using AcquireTokenSilentAsync method. More Details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734558/4689622

Thanks All